# Jupyter notebook large lists

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

The following code snippet has a runtime 
of around 1 min in jupyter notebook and below 1 
second in the ipython shell:

```
test_list = []
max_len = 1000
for i in range(max_len):
    test_list.append(np.random.randn(784))
```

Can somebody reproduce this issue or is it specific to my environment?

I'm not sure what could cause the issue and would
be glad if someone could help.

edit1: Figured that this problem is specific to my environment.

[installed packages](https://pastebin.com/vLjDPqMD)

Comment: I'm assuming this isn't your actual use case? but in case it is, you can just do `np.random.randn(784,1000)`

Comment: No it is not directly my usecase. I read in the data actually and then transform it into lists. I noticed that with another environment I don't face the issue. I wonder what package is causing the issue though.

Comment: Can you clarify: does the above code snippet show the performance difference, or does your code (which is paraphrased above) show the performance difference?

Comment: Excuse me I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. The code snippet I presented has the same issue as the one Dan suggested. The snippet is my attempt at a minimal example. I removed more and more from my initial code until I found out that it is the list creation that is causing the troubles.